# Working with zero's (0) in PHP

Tags: php

I'm creating a calculator in PHP and wondered the best method to check a `$_POST` variable, I need the calculator to process all numbers including `0`. And to fail if the field is empty.

This sounds easy but `is_null`, `!empty` & `isset` I cannot seem to get to work.

Comment: Use the type comparison? `if ($var === 0) { /* true if it's the number 0 */ }`

Comment: Also, http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: For starters: `$valid = isset($_POST['var']) && is_numeric($_POST['var'])`

Comment: Please post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try to hardcode this http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php into your brain :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that if you use text inputs in your form they will always be set, and `isset()` will return `true`.  They are set but may be empty in which case `empty()` would make sense, however it returns `true` for `0`.  `is_null()` doesn't make sense here at at all.

```
if(!is_numeric($_POST['something'])) {
    echo "Must be a number";
}
```

If you construct the inputs as an array like: `<input name="numbers[first]" ...>` then you can filter it easily:

```
$numbers = array_filter($_POST['numbers'], 'is_numeric');

if(!isset($numbers['first'])) {
    echo "Must be a number";
}
```

You can also check into [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for more possibilities.

Comment: Please note that `is_numeric` also matches floats, and strings looking like  scientific notation, which may lead to bugs in your code if you're expecting integers.

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping that a calculator will handle `floats` ;-)